# How should I do exception handling in my database python code for no data fetched from server or connection time out

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

psycopg2.DatabaseError: could not receive data from server: Connection timed out

Comment: I have user defined exception classes ConnectionError, CursorError, QueryError. Now in my query_execute() it ran update query, and raised above error:connection time out, and exited the program. Where should i add exception handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code in your :

```
 def retrieve_data(db, table_name):
    try:
        comm ="SELECT * FROM {};".format(table_name)
        with db.connect() as conn:
            column_of_sql_table = conn.execute(comm).fetchall()
        return pd.DataFrame(column_of_sql_table)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return pd.DataFrame()

df = retrieve_data(db, table_name)
if not df.empty :
    < do what ever you want>
else: 
    < rise error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside try/except block.
like:

```
try:
   conn = conn = dbapi.connect(user=<>,password=<>,host=<>,database=<>)
except psycopg2.DatabaseError:
   <whatever code>
```

Comment: Why does psycopg2.DatabaseError occurs? While I looked into the logs, it was running update sql query and did not compete the execution.

Comment: 1. Does the connection get lost frequently for that update statement?
2. Was it taking long for the update statement?
3. Is it an isolated connection lost case or you had bunch of concurrent connection lost failures?

Comment: 1.No, it has happened ~10 times in past 6 months. 2. It seems to stall when processing large amount of data.

Comment: The connection getting lost is just the manifestation of the underlying performance problem of the update statement that needs fixed. Perhaps you need to enhance your code to estimate the update volume and then take different measures for small volume update and big volume update. If you share details on your update statements , we can discuss.